# Executig lots of batch files on windows using TCL

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exec, tcl

Here I wrote a script that should execute all files in current directory. They are batch fils.

```
set path [pwd]
append path "/"
set files [glob *]
foreach file $files {
    exec cmd.exe /c ${path}$file
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the script but in batch file. There were some commands in it using path that were absent.